# Get live video stream in c# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ip-camera

I'm using Unity3D c# and want to read a video feed to display on a texture.

The issue here is that I would like to get the video from a live feed e.g. IP Camera. Guessing similar sites like [this](http://www.stickam.com/) or [this](http://bambuser.com/broadcasts) uses similar techniques live. Also testing against apps like [this](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ip-cam/id333208495?mt=8.)

Don't really know where to start, trying out TCPListener and Socket but can't really use a url, just ip and port.

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution is to fetch single frames from image server application that provide such a feature. An example of such a technique can be found in [Unity3d documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.LoadImageIntoTexture.html) 
A simple Image server to test that setup could be any IP-cam application. 
See [this article](http://www.stareat.it/sp.aspx?g=30b7f8238c52453b8bb4978b63577d33) for details.